# Python conversion of json to just display list

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

Wondering if I could have some expert help here. In python, I want to convert this json. Currently it is:

```
{
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}
```

and I want it to come out like this. With really just the comicname list:

```
{
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The "json" module provides functions to convert this json to a Python dict. Then with "del" you can remove the unwanted key.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things here. The first one I suggest for your request.

**Code1**
Deletes *"comics":"marvel*

```
x = {
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}
del x["comics"]
print(x)
```

**Code2**
Just shows *"comicname":list[]*

```
x = {
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}
x = x["comicname"]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

my_dict = {
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}

# Remove unwanted key.
del my_dict["comics"]

# Turn dictionary into json string and print it.
print(json.dumps(my_dict))
```

You should check out the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick options:

1 - Create a New object

```
original_object = {
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}

new_object = {
    'comicname': original_object['comicname']
    }

print(new_object)
```

2 - Delete 'comics' from the original one:

```
original_object = {
    "comics": "marvel",
    "comicname": [
        "Spiderman",
        "Avengers",
        "Captain Marvel"
    ]
}

del original_object["comics"]
print(original_object)
```